# where to use bean springTaskSessionFactory in JBPM process execution?

Tags: spring, jpa, jbpm

i got an example of spring configuration with jbpm here     http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Final/droolsjbpm-integration-docs/html/ch.spring.html and i have implemented it.There is a bean called **springTaskSessionFactory** ,i don't get where this bean will be used in **human task execution** ?

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:jbpm="http://drools.org/schema/drools-spring"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://drools.org/schema/drools-spring org/drools/container/spring/drools-spring-1.2.0.xsd">
  <!-- persistence & transactions-->
  <bean id="htEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<property name="persistenceUnitName" value="org.jbpm.task" />
 </bean>
  <bean id="htEm" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
<property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="htEmf"/>
</bean>
<bean id="jpaTxMgr" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
<property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="htEmf" />
<!-- this must be true if using the SharedEntityManagerBean, and false otherwise -->
<property name="nestedTransactionAllowed" value="true"/>
</bean>
<bean id="htTxMgr"     class="org.drools.container.spring.beans.persistence.HumanTaskSpringTransactionManager">
<constructor-arg ref="jpaTxMgr" />
 </bean>
<!-- human-task beans -->
 <bean id="systemEventListener" class="org.drools.SystemEventListenerFactory" factory-method="getSystemEventListener" />
  <bean id="taskService" class="org.jbpm.task.service.TaskService" >
  <property name="systemEventListener" ref="systemEventListener" />
  </bean>
 <bean id="springTaskSessionFactory"        class="org.jbpm.task.service.persistence.TaskSessionSpringFactoryImpl"
    init-method="initialize" depends-on="taskService" >
<!-- if using the SharedEntityManagerBean, make sure to enable nested transactions -->
<property name="entityManager" ref="htEm" />
<property name="transactionManager" ref="htTxMgr" />
<property name="useJTA" value="false" />
<property name="taskService" ref="taskService" />
 </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Did you solved your problem?